# Vertical SeekBar behaves strangely when initiated on a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, seekbar

I'm using a simple Vertical SeekBar that is working fine if I initiate it on the onCreate function. But if I initiate the SeekBar on a different thread the thumb position does not work as expected.

The code I'm using to initiate the SeekBar:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
AbsoluteLayout mainLayout;  
VerticalSeekBar seekBar;
Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    context=this;
    mainLayout=(AbsoluteLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout_id);           
    Thread thread1 =new Thread(runnable1);
    thread1.start();            
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
private Runnable runnable1 = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {                 
        seekBar=new VerticalSeekBar(context);       
        loadMainScreen.sendEmptyMessage(0);         
    }
};

Handler loadMainScreen = new Handler() {
    @Override       
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {              
        super.handleMessage(msg);
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams parameters = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(40,200,150,30);
            mainLayout.addView(seekBar,parameters);             
        }   
};  
  }
```

I do not think the problem is on the SeekBar but I will show the code anyway.

```
public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {  

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    c.rotate(-90);
    c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

    super.onDraw(c);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (!isEnabled()) {
        return false;
    }

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
        onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        break;
    }
    return true;
}   

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
 }
```

I try changing the Context I'm passing to the variable context to getApplicationContext() and getBaseContext() but it did not work.

If I put the initialization on a runOnUiThread it crashes because the SeekBar is not initialized when I try to add to the layout. If I put both the initialization and the addView on a runOnUiThread it works but that is not what I want.

I was wondering if there is something I could do regarding the Context to make it work. Any different ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Uh, you have to do anything related to the UI on the UI thread. It won't work properly otherwise. THere is no other option.

Comment: but im not updating the ui, im just initiating the vertical SeekBar, and it works fine on a regular seekbar